# Bootstrap doesn't load directly

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a problem with my VueJs frontend, I have a BootstrapVue navbar component, my problem is that when the page loads (or reloads), there is a small amount of time that the navbar is displayed without loading the bootstrap, this is quite annoying.

Here is my navbar code:

```
<div id="navbar">
<b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="light" variant="light">
{% if user.is_authenticated and user.is_staff %} 
<b-navbar-brand href="{% url 'home' %}"> Inicio </b-navbar-brand>
<b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
<b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
  
  <b-navbar-nav>            
    <!-- Navbar dropdowns -->
    <b-nav-item-dropdown text="Maestros">
      <b-dropdown-item href="#">Candidatos</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item href="#">Candidaturas</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item href="#">Centros</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item href="#">Circunscripciones</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item href="{% url 'elecciones' %}">Elecciones</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item href="#">Estudios</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item href="{% url 'locales' %}">Locales de votación</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item href="#">Mesas</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item href="#">Urnas</b-dropdown-item>
    </b-nav-item-dropdown>

    <b-nav-item-dropdown text="Personas" right>
      <b-dropdown-item href="#">Account</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item href="#">Settings</b-dropdown-item>
    </b-nav-item-dropdown>

    <b-nav-item-dropdown text="Datos Personales" right>
      <b-dropdown-item href="#">Account</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item href="#">Settings</b-dropdown-item>
    </b-nav-item-dropdown>
    <b-nav-item-dropdown text="Consulta Censo" right>
      <b-dropdown-item href="#">Account</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item href="#">Settings</b-dropdown-item>
    </b-nav-item-dropdown>
    <b-nav-item-dropdown text="Seguimiento" right>
      <b-dropdown-item href="#">Account</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item href="#">Settings</b-dropdown-item>
    </b-nav-item-dropdown>
    <b-nav-item-dropdown text="Resultados" right>
      <b-dropdown-item href="#">Account</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item href="#">Settings</b-dropdown-item>
    </b-nav-item-dropdown>
  </b-navbar-nav>
  {% endif %}
  <!-- Right aligned nav items -->
  <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}            
      <b-nav-item href="{% url 'logout' %}">{{ user.username }} - Cerrar sesión</b-nav-item>
    {% endif %}
  </b-navbar-nav>
</b-collapse>
```

And below I define the element:

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js">   </script>
 <script src="//unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
 <script>
   new Vue({ el: '#navbar' });
 </script>
```

Comment: Hi, trying to debug something without actual context/code/[repro] is quite annoying too tbh.

Comment: Apologies, I was on vacation, I have edited the post adding the code of my navbar

Comment: Why do you use a CDN rather than an NPM package?

Comment: I'm not using the npm package, it's a new project and I'm learning about Django + VueJs, and I followed a tutorial that did it this way

Comment: The fact that you're using a CDN introduces some latency because you need to download the actual package from a remote server.